# ¿que hacer con los usuarios que en ningún momento llegan a verificar su cuenta luego de un registro?

Tags: nodejs, angular, registro

Estoy trabajando en algo personal pero estoy tratando de hacerlo lo mejor que puedo tomando en cuenta que estoy aprendiendo a medida que voy avanzando. Tengo un registro de usuarios donde cada usuario ingresa su correo, clave y nombres y posteriormente envío un enlace de confirmación (el cuál tiene una fecha de espiración de 24 horas) a su correo electrónico. Si el usuario ingresa a su correo y se verifica que el link enviado es válido procedo a activar su cuenta estableciendo en 1 la columna cuenta_activa en la base de datos, hasta aquí todo bien. Pero me surgió está duda:

¿que hacer si el usuario por alguna u otra razón nunca verifica su cuenta? Por ahí leí que se podría programar una tarea en el CRON por ejemplo, que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo y que esta elimine todos los usuarios registrados que no verificaron su cuenta y que obviamente tengan el link vencido.

Pero... que hacer con este caso: Si la tarea se ejecuta cada 24 horas, y un link vence unos minutos después y el usuario se quiere registrar de nuevo no se podrá registrar ya que el usuario aún está registrado y se eliminaría sería el siguiente día, lo que se me ocurre es que la tarea se ejecute mas veces por día, para reducir las probabilidades de este caso de uso, pero aún así podría ocurrir. No se me ha ocurrido otra solución, por eso recurro a este foro. Alguien con mas experiencia ha tenido este inconveniente? quisiera saber cuál sería la mejor opción.

Estoy trabajando con Node.js y Angular. No dejo un código de que lo que tengo por que siento que mi pregunta se basa mas en una solución en base a estrategia mas que a código. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar. Saludos!

Comment: Si un usuario se vuelve a registrar sin estar activado bastaría con que actualizaras la fecha de expiración.

Comment: si el usuario intenta iniciar se sesión pero nunca verifico su cuenta muestra un mensaje que dice que debe verificar su cuenta, asi que debe ir al correo y hacer click en el link. si el link ya expirado para entonces, lo mejor seria decirle que se registre nuevamente ?

Comment: Si su link ha expirado, a efectos prácticos es como si hubieras borrado el usuario (antes o después el cron lo va a borrar). Yo me haría el loco y lo aceptaría como un registro nuevo, borrando/archivando su registro expirado e insertándolo de nuevo con los nuevos datos que me dé.

Comment: ok, pero debo indicarle algo si el link ha expirado cuando intente verificar su cuenta... estoy medio enrredado en como hacerlo de la mejor manera para el usuario, para indicarle los pasos que debe seguir si el link expiró.

Comment: Si pasa eso, indícale que su plazo de verificación ha expirado, y pregúntale si quiere que le envíes otro email de verificación (para el que tendrá otras 24 horas). Si te dice que sí, actualizas su fecha de expiración y le envías un nuevo email.

Comment: Ok, entonces no será necesario hacer una tarea de con para eliminar los usuarios que no verificaron y que su link expiró?

Comment: Lo que yo haría sería indicarle al usuario el estado vencido de su link y proponerle la posibilidad de solicitar un nuevo link o ponerse en contacto con el administrador. Esto lo puedes hacer tanto al momento de que el usuario hace clic en el link vencido o si intenta ingresar (login) con la cuenta aún sin confirmar o si intenta volver a registrarse cuando ya hay un registro pendiente. De todas formas, es lo que **yo haría**. Tu lógica puede variar de acuerdo a lo que tú quieras hacer. Saludos.

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras Y para resolver el caso de que el usuario intenta validar su cuenta 2 meses después, se que es un caso muy extraño pero puede ocurrir. Harías lo mismo?

Comment: No lo dudes, creo que establecería una política de 6 meses y se lo informaría al usuario. Luego eliminaría el registro no activado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es guardar la fecha que se genero el registro, cuando intente verificar su correo validar que no pasen mas de las 24 horas, validando fecha actual vs fecha de registro, si ya paso le generas un error y que vuelva a registrar.

Cuando ejecutes tu tarea de depuración valida que borre todo lo que tenga mas de 24 horas de registro, así siempre aseguras que nunca se va a poder verificar un link expirado y tu tarea tiene asegurado que es lo que va a borrar.

Comment: yo guardo la fecha de expiración del hash en el formato año-mes-dia, por ejemplo: 2020-06-24, entonces, cuándo valido lo hago en la base de datos así: ``` (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),hash_expiracion) <= 1 ``` . Creo que lo que mas me tiene pensando es como guiar al usuario si el link ha expirado, por ejemplo en login, si no ha activado su cuenta y se que el link no ha expirado le digo que revise su correo para que la verifique? y si se que ya expiro lo mando directo a registrarse y elimino todo el registro anterior como me indicaron arriba? o como sería la mejor expirencia de usuario?